# WTRN0124I: When the timeout occurred the thread

Tags: websphere, ibm-mq, websphere-7, websphere-6.1

I am getting the below error.Kindly help

***[8/8/14 21:14:56:939 GMT-08:00] 00000005 TimeoutManage I   WTRN0006W: Transaction 00000147B92EFAE20000000100000012DF462C9E681BA3670A44A25FE1B0F6182303FB5C00000147B92EFAE20000000100000012DF462C9E681BA3670A44A25FE1B0F6182303FB5C00000001 has timed out after 120 seconds.***

**[8/8/14 21:14:56:967 GMT-08:00] 00000006 TimeoutManage I   WTRN0124I: When the timeout occurred the thread with which the transaction is, or was most recently, associated was Thread[WMQJCAResourceAdapter : 4,5,main]. The stack trace of this thread when the timeout occurred was:**

```
java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite0(Native Method)
java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite(SocketOutputStream.java:103)
java.net.SocketOutputStream.write(SocketOutputStream.java:147)
com.ibm.mq.jmqi.remote.internal.RemoteTCPConnection.send(RemoteTCPConnection.java:1212)
com.ibm.mq.jmqi.remote.internal.system.RemoteConnection.sendTSH(RemoteConnection.java:2289)
com.ibm.mq.jmqi.remote.internal.RemoteHconn.sendTSH(RemoteHconn.java:954)
com.ibm.mq.jmqi.remote.internal.RemoteFAP.jmqiPut(RemoteFAP.java:5443)
com.ibm.mq.jmqi.remote.internal.RemoteFAP.MQPUT(RemoteFAP.java:5205)
com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.v6.base.internal.MQSESSION.MQPUT(MQSESSION.java:1252)
com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.v6.base.internal.MQQueue.putMsg2(MQQueue.java:2090)
com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.v6.jms.internal.MQMessageProducer.sendInternal(MQMessageProducer.java:1262)
com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.v6.jms.internal.MQMessageProducer.send(MQMessageProducer.java:768)
com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.v6.jms.internal.MQMessageProducer.send(MQMessageProducer.java:2713)
com.ibm.msg.client.jms.internal.JmsMessageProducerImpl.sendMessage(JmsMessageProducerImpl.java:872)
com.ibm.msg.client.jms.internal.JmsMessageProducerImpl.send_(JmsMessageProducerImpl.java:727)
com.ibm.msg.client.jms.internal.JmsMessageProducerImpl.send(JmsMessageProducerImpl.java:398)
com.ibm.mq.jms.MQMessageProducer.send(MQMessageProducer.java:281)
com.ibm.ejs.jms.JMSQueueSenderHandle.send(JMSQueueSenderHandle.java:204)
com.scb.sts.stsappserver.sender.MessageSender.sendRecords(Unknown Source)
com.scb.sts.services.PCSPPaymentSplitter.doExecute(Unknown Source)
com.scb.sts.stsappserver.eventhandler.SplitterEventHandler.handleEvent(Unknown Source)
com.scb.sts.services.PCSPPaymentReceiver.doProcess(Unknown Source)
com.scb.sts.services.PCSPPaymentReceiver.doExecute(Unknown Source)
com.scb.sts.controllers.OCWSServlet.doPost(Unknown Source)
com.scb.sts.qlcomm.QLCommBean.processXMLFile(Unknown Source)
com.scb.sts.qlcomm.QLCommBean.isDoOutput(Unknown Source)
com.scb.sts.qlcomm.QLCommBean.onMessage(Unknown Source)
com.ibm.ejs.container.MessageEndpointHandler.invokeMdbMethod(MessageEndpointHandler.java:1093)
com.ibm.ejs.container.MessageEndpointHandler.invoke(MessageEndpointHandler.java:778)
$Proxy32.onMessage(Unknown Source)
com.ibm.mq.connector.inbound.MessageEndpointWrapper.onMessage(MessageEndpointWrapper.java:131)
com.ibm.mq.jms.MQSession$FacadeMessageListener.onMessage(MQSession.java:147)
com.ibm.msg.client.jms.internal.JmsSessionImpl.run(JmsSessionImpl.java:2557)
com.ibm.mq.jms.MQSession.run(MQSession.java:860)
com.ibm.mq.connector.inbound.WorkImpl.run(WorkImpl.java:172)
com.ibm.ejs.j2c.work.WorkProxy.run(WorkProxy.java:399)
com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1604)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The transaction timeout simply means that the transaction not was committed before the timeout expired, in this case 120s elapsed without a commit.

The stack shows that you're in the onMessage() function of an MDB named QLCommBean. And that this MDB was sending some messages via MessageSender.sendRecords(), which in turn was called the MQ JMS API:

JMSQueueSenderHandle.send()

The top of the stack is:

java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite0(Native Method)

This means that the active code within the MDB at the time of the transaction timeout, was a socket write (sending data over the network). In this case MQ was sending a message to the queue manager.

The transaction timeout itself is not a bug. You need to review the MDB logic and determine if 120s is an appropriate amount of time to be in the MDB. If it isn't, I suggest you add logging to your MDB to find out what it was doing for 120s. It *may* be that the MQ code has used up a lot of this time, but it may not be. The stack shown is just where the code happened to be 120s after onMessage() was invoked.

As MQ in the process of sending data over the network to the queue manager, you may want to look at your network to see if its performing adequately, or possibly your queue manager. It might be heavily loaded.

If this occurs regularly, one good option is to take a number of javacores over the course of the 120s. You can then see what the stack was at various points.

Otherwise I suggest:

1) Instrument your MDB, make sure you know which code was executed, and at what time. Only this will rule out your MDB logic.
2) Consider your network
3) Possibly trace your queue manager & the MQ JMS code - you may need IBM's help to determine if the time taken by the IBM code is appropriate
4) If 120s is an acceptable length of time for onMessage(), consider increasing the transaction timeout value to a value greater than the maximum time you consider to be acceptable for onMessage().